# C#/C++ Prevent external application window from popping into the foreground

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, interop

I want to prevent a specific window that belongs to an external application from coming to the foreground, or even better to prevent it from shifting in the z-order at all.

I am aware of LockSetForeground, but this blocks all other applications windows from coming to foreground which is overkill for my needs and it also hasn't been 100% reliable for me.

Is there a simple way to temporarily lock another windows position in the z-order?  Obviously I can let it come to the foreground and then put it back where it was in the z-order but this is flickery and doesn't provide a smooth UX.

Comment: Little you can do, uninstalling such poorly behaving apps is certainly best.  There's a programmer somewhere that can help you, you will not find him here.  Pick up the phone.

Comment: So that window sits in background and then forcefully focuses itself?

Comment: @user2802841 yes, it foregrounds itself when a specific event that I need to trigger occurs and I don't want it to.

Comment: Maybe disabling the window with [EnableWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enablewindow) function?

Comment: EnableWindow is an interesting idea, will try thanks